# 404 Error Document not found - CSS stylesheet not loaded in erb file with absolute file path on localhost

Tags: css, ruby, http-status-code-404, erb

I am trying to apply a css style sheet to an erb file in sinatra, but when loading on localhost with rack I keep getting a 404 error telling me the file cannot be found.

It feels like I have tried everything from changing file paths to adding type, rel, media to the html tag but nothing seems to work. I am really stumped.

**My HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9292/public/styles/home.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> I am working </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My CSS**

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Any help would be majorly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image: My file structure]

[image: Error Message on Chrome]

Comment: What web server are you using? Can you navigate to `http://localhost:9292/public` ?

Comment: I can't unfortunately. Just tried and it kicks me back to 'sinatra doesn't know this ditty"

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the issue**

As almost suspected, the file path to my css wasn't resolving properly. For the longest time I had no idea why, but it seems that shotgun/sinatra wasn't serving up the files properly.

I'm still not entirely sure what's going on but there is a really good bit of help which I found here:

[Github Repo](https://github.com/Integralist/Passage)

With a bit of a tutorial here:

[Ruby/Sinatra Framework](http://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/sinatra.html)

Kudos to the guy. It's 1:30am and it finally worked.